# Ошибка при запуске pycharm-community-2019.3.3

Tags: ide, python-3.6, pycharm

Пытаюсь открыть IDE:

`sh pycharm.sh`

Вот что высерает терминал:

**OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Error: Could not find or load main class 0
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 0**

Версия Java:
openjdk 11.0.6 2020-01-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.6+10-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu118.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.6+10-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu118.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: PyCharm должен использовать забандленную JDK (`<pycharm>/jre`). У вас почему то используется установленная на системе OpenJDK. Как было установлено IDE? Хелп топик про выбор JDK https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under